# How can I create a similar application to YouTube on Blockchain? What is the cost of it?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

How can I create a similar application to YouTube on Blockchain or as a smart contract? What is the cost of it?. I am keen on picking it up as a project.
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look also at [theta](https://www.theta.tv)

Answer (score 0):

A very similar blockchain-based website that has already been created, is [steemit.com](https://steemit.com/). It will reward you with a cryptocurrency called STEEM.

for more information visit the website and read its [whitepaper](https://steem.com/SteemWhitePaper.pdf).